# Getting Javascript value in Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, beautifulsoup, request

I am currently writing a script that prints the content of a page and then extracts the data I need for a future request payload.

I am unable though to locate a certain value named "dfValue" it seems to be located within Javascript so when I try and extract the "dfValue" content I can only get a blank response.

The dfValue snippet is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/hpp/js/df.js?v=20170531"></script>

<div id="df_swf_c" style="display:none;"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="dfValue" id="dfValue" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    dfDo("dfValue");
    //]]>
</script>
```

With similar values on the page I am able to extract it by simply using code such as.

```
soup.find(None, {'name': 'dfValue'}).get('value')
```

but this does not work, is there a particular way I am able to extract the dfValue?

Advise is appreciated.

Comment: What does `dfDo("dfValue")` do? Are you sure the input `dfValue` is not empty?

Comment: I simply copied and pasted the dfValue content of the page, when I try to extract the dfValue by using soup python returns a blank line.

Comment: I think **dfValue** is itself a value and only the input parameter for function **dfDo**.  You need to check what exactly dfDo is doing. If it sets some DOM object then you can fetch them via python.

Comment: @ManinderSingh is there anyway you can help me with this? I am really struggling

Comment: Can you give the `url`??

Answer (score 0):

That `input` element is **not** within Javascript. It's accessible. As shown here, the `name` of the `input` element is 'dfValue' and its `value` is '' (an empty string).

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(open('temp.htm'), 'lxml')
>>> input = soup.find('input')
>>> input.attrs['name']
'dfValue'
>>> input.attrs['value']
''
```

If you need to be able to enter data into this field, or otherwise manipulate this form, then you could consider using the selenium library.